# Canvas on a javascript image slider

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, slider

So I need to be able to put item text on a white background image when an item doesn't have a picture. Although, I'm a bit unsure of how canvas will interact with my slider. I'm using slick slider at the moment.

Here is my code for loading my images upon searching for items.

```
   for (const image of imagePath) {

   const img = document.createElement("img");
   if (image.slice(0,5) == "shelf"){
   img.src = `/check/assets/img/${image}`;
   }
   else{
   img.src = '/check/assets/img/noimage.png';
   }

   img.classList.add("new");
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.id = `${image}`
   div.classList.add("image");

   document.getElementById('search-slider').appendChild(div);
   document.getElementById(image).appendChild(img);


   }



   // need to make the images line up
   $('.search-items').slick('unslick').slick('reinit');
   $('.search-items').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
   infinite: false, //true
   slidesToShow: 8,
   slidesToScroll: 8,
   arrows: true,
   centerMode: false,
   width: 200,
   prevArrow: $('.prev'),
   nextArrow: $('.next')
   });
```

This is the code I was going to try to implement into this code to try and get it to work.
https://jsfiddle.net/tqymo4f7/4/

I know that this line determines the location of the where the text starts. 
 `fillTextLine(context, text, 0,25);`

However, I'm not sure if this will affect the location of the text in relation to the total screen size or (div)the area of the image in the slider. I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

Thanks for any help. Let me know if you need clarification on something.

Comment: It’s using the `fillText` method of the 2D canvas context, so it is relative to the canvas …

Comment: I see. So as long as I have my canvas in a div it should work?